# Issues and new log entries after upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04

Tags: log, 19.04

I have just successfully upgraded from Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04. The first problem I had was that my Dash-to-Dock extension didn't work, but I fixed that by running `sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` and re-booting.

Remaining problems I have noticed are:

1) The touchpad cannot be enabled after logging on. It works during the login but not afterwards. I am using a bluetooth mouse instead and previously use the Gnome extension "Touchpad indicator" under 18.10 to automatically switch between mouse and touchpad but this extension doesn't work under 19.10 so I have removed the extension.

2) I have the following new warnings in my logs after logging in:

> Hardware: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
>   Other: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
>   System: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e